# If my iPhone app makes an API call to my server - can someone log the URL?

Tags: ios, security, logging

Let's say my app does something like this:

```
NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myserver.com/json.php"];

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]];
```

If someone logs the network traffic of my app, will they be able to see that there is a request made to "http://www.myserver.com/json.php", or is this somehow encrypted?

What if it's a post request? Will the parameters show up in their logs?

EDIT to expand on the problem - I'm not using https - how would I go about securely deleting something from the database using PHP?

Let's say it would look something like this:

```
NSString *requestDeleteURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myserver.com/delete.php?deleteID=232$user=343"];
```

This would allow anyone who logged my app's network traffic to simply build a script to delete the database. Even if I passed some kind of token via URL, this token would then also be visible and thus completely useless. What's the fundamental flaw in my thought process?

Comment: It might be useful to discuss why this is a concern in the first place. The reasoning I usually see here is that you have credentials or some other sensitive data you want to trust the client not to copy or manipulate. That's a dead end; users with an incentive to find it will be able to dig up any data you include in the client. If it is important then you need to find another security model which does not depend on trusting the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is possible, easy, and a useful debugging tool you should be familiar with for your own use.

HTTP requests are trivial to capture. HTTPS traffic requires slightly more work and (hopefully) cooperation from the end user but certainly doesn't protect your server from your own users.

My preferred tools for this is http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/ but there are exist any number of alternatives.

---

I think the missing piece here is server-side authentication and authorization.

You want authentication to identify who the user is; this is usually a cookie or token sent in response to an authentication challenge but could be as simple as a token generated by the client app if you are willing to give up device portability in exchange for not requiring a login. The essential point is that you have some sort of unguessable secret for each client instead of sending a predictable value like a user id.

Once you can verify user identity then you can enforce authorization checks on each request sent to the server. For example just because we know who someone is does not mean they can delete anything. Perhaps users can only delete data they created?

Answer (score 0):

The requested URL itself will always be visible. What you post or receive over that request can be encrypted by using https. So never put any information you want to hide from other people in the URL string and always encrypt using https if you post or receive sensitive data like logins or personal information.

This is a basic example of sending POST data with your request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *bodydata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@",jsonString];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[bodydata UTF8String] length:bodydata.length];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
```

This works exactly the same as sending POST data from a HTML-form for your webserver.